# Convert / replace newline to &nbsp;

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to replace Newline with &nbsp I am searching on google but not get perfect answer.

This is my string

```
$string = 'multiple


newline



convert




or replace';
```

I am using

```
str_replace(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, PHP_EOL.'&nbsp;'.PHP_EOL, $string);
```

but output:

```
multiple
&nbsp;

newline
&nbsp;

&nbsp;
convert
&nbsp;

&nbsp;

or replace
```

The result should be:

```
multiple

&nbsp;

newline

&nbsp;

&nbsp;

convert

&nbsp;

&nbsp;

&nbsp;

or replace
```

Any one help please to solve this problem...

Comment: `nl2br()` might help

Comment: I am also try nl2br(); function but that doesn't seems to work....  if you have any other suggestion please explain....

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Maybe we can solve this in other way?

Comment: This for wordpress frontent post. In wordpress this string save database as my expected result. But in frontent post stiring doesn't save database like result.

Comment: Not clear. What and where do you save?

Comment: In Wordpress when i write post_content like string via backend the post_content will save database like my result. But when I write post_content via frontend this post content doesn't save database like my result.... If this is not clear please try to help another way... thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of adding `&nbsp;`?

Comment: This will show line break in single.php post_content

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that your problem is somewhere else, but here's my solution, using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$string = 'multiple


newline



convert




or replace';
$r = preg_replace_callback(
    '/' . PHP_EOL . '(' . PHP_EOL . '+)' . PHP_EOL . '/',
    function($v) {
        return PHP_EOL .PHP_EOL . implode(PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, array_fill(0, strlen($v[1]), '&nbsp;')) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL ;
    },
    $string
);

echo $r;
```

Comment: multiple

&nbsp;

&nbsp;

newline

&nbsp;

&nbsp;


convert

&nbsp;

&nbsp;



or replace   this is result